# Filenames and identifiers with @ symbols

Tags: vim

I'd like to be able to search for words with @ symbols and `gf` to files with the same pattern, e.g., foo@bar.

```
set iskeyword-=@
```

(or changing the setting from `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,.`
to   `iskeyword=48-57,_,192-255,.` allows me to use `*` to search for foo@bar instances, but if I do `set isfname-=@`, I still can't `gf` to it (assuming foo@bar is a file in path).

How do I make `foo@bar` gf-able?

Comment: `set isfname-=@` removes the `@` from `isf` set. You don't want that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a file named `foo@bar` and you want to edit it hitting `gf` on its path, you could add the `@` character to the `'isfname'` option like this:

```
set isf+=@-@
```

Note that for the `'isfname'` and `'iskeyword'` options, `@` doesn't stand for the `@` character, it stands for all the characters where `isalpha()` returns true.

Relevant section from `:h 'isf`:

```
If the character is '@', all characters where isalpha() returns TRUE
are included.  Normally these are the characters a to z and A to Z,
plus accented characters.  To include '@' itself use "@-@".
```